# Design-Pattern for a Service like Architecture

Tags: android, design-patterns

What Design-Pattern would be intelligent in which following Components(simplified) exists:

3 Components
- GUI 
- Data fetcher
- Database

[image: Design]

I have no Access to the Server in the Internet, its just a Data-Source. The Data which lays in the Internet is always the newer one, the local-Database is just a copy(cache) of the one in the Internet. The GUI can request and update of the local cache, the Service-like-component fetches then asynchronously the newest data, which could take awhile.
The GUI shows only Data from the local Database, which he can fetch synchronously.

So my Question is, what classes would you use for the maybe longterm running Service with Progressbar capabilities ? Are there better Designs for this kind of "problem"? Are there better practices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the Service Like Component:

- An interface (method) to kick off the update process. Typically this service would return a `jobId` to indicate a job that is being processed in the background
- Another interface (method) to get the status based on a particular `jobId`. The implementation of this service could return a status, percentCompleted or any other relevant info that will tell the caller the current status of the update process. The implementation of this method needs to be able to report an incremental progress (such as reporting the incremental store in the local storage) in order to make an accurate progress bar, otherwise the best the UI could do is show the spinning progress bar.

  - Note that if such incremental reporting is not possible to implement then the Update process should probably use a typical `AsyncTask` usage which execute update in the background and report to the user when it is finished. If this operation might take a while, you could implement the completion of the update via Android notification bar or push notification.

Assuming you have the interface to get the progress of the update, you could utilize the [AsyncTask onProgressUpdate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onProgressUpdate%28Progress...%29) to report the progress of the update. The method is specifically designed for that.

Your steps are roughly as follow:

- Execute the interface to update via one AsyncTask. Since your update is happening asynchronously, this particular task should return fairly quickly with a status reporting whether the execution is running successfully or fail because some exception along with the jobId that it is currently executing
- Launch another AsyncTask that is pinging the status of the update and report the progress via `onProgressUpdate`. The AsyncTask roughly looks like

```
public class GetUpdateStatusAsyncTask extends AsyncTask {
    protected Integer doInBackground(Integer... param) {
        // this is the jobId that you get from the previous AsyncTask that you use to kick off the 
        // the update process
        int jobId = param[0];
        double percentCompleted  = fetchStatus(jobId);

        while(percentCompleted != 100.00) {
            publishProgress(percentCompleted);
        }

        // return status code
        return 1;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Double... progress) {
        // set the progressBar here
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
       // done, handle status code
    }

    private double fetchStatus(int jobId) {
        double percentCompleted = 0.0;
        // call interface to get the update based on the jobId
        // return percentCompleted status or make a more complex object if you need 
        // more detail info
        return percentCompleted;
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe i should clarify my first post more. I have not access to the Server in the Internet. Its just a Data-Source, the newest one. I grab the Data and update the local-Database.

Comment: If the Service Like Component is a local class, in order to report progress accurately, there is still a need for interface to be able to get the current progress within this class. Without the availability of that interface, the best you could do is to show the spinning progress bar and wait until the update is finished. I will update the answer

Comment: looks good but why do you want to launch another asynctask to poll the progress of the first one ?

Comment: If you want the update from the data in internet asynchronous as you described and get the progress as well, you would need two threads running (one to get the update via internet, the other is to poll the progress).  Otherwise, the one that gets the data will block the progress polling. If incremental progress reporting is possible, the first AsyncTask described should be probably launched from within the ServiceLikeComponent and it doesn't need to be manifested as an AsyncTask (alternatively you could code it as Runnable in a Thread).